# Arabic font is not correct in Mac and iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, fonts, arabic

Good day,
I'm trying to use "TheMixArab" font in my iOS application but the font is not showing correctly.

This is how it shows in xCode and iPhone:[image]

and this is how it shows in Pages application :[image]

but it shows right in photoshop : [image]

Can any one helps ?

Comment: You should probably include the text, ***as text*** (not an image), somewhere in your question. Also, your first image looks like an entirely different font, so I suspect you've simply failed to include the font in your app properly. Beyond that, while I don't read Arabic, it seems that this font uses custom ligatures or cursive connections which may need to be enabled. For example, see TextEdit > Format > Font > Show Fonts > Action/gear menu > Typography.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with a lot of OSX applications — in general they don't connect the Arabic letters correctly. (The Mac version of Microsoft Word does the same thing and has for *years*, they've never fixed it.)

The only word processing program (that I know of) on Mac that does Arabic right is the TextEdit. All the Adobe programs used to do the same thing (on both Windows and OSX), but thankfully they've fixed it.

I've never built an iPhone application in XCode, so I can't help you with that part. But there are plenty of iPhone apps which do Arabic perfectly well, so there must be a way.

Good luck!